# understanding upper bound and lower bound in lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders, bounded-variation

i am studying **discrete math**.
have a topic **lattices**, i really cant understand how to find **greatest lower bound and lowest upper bound.** any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It’s awfully hard to help in a vacuum; it would be much better to ask about a specific problem.

Comment: sir, please help me to find out glb and lub in a any hasse diagram @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: what about the glb?

Comment: For the greatest lower bound just turn the Hasse diagram upside-down and then find the least upper bound in the inverted diagram. If you do that with $e$ and $t$, for instance, in the partial order in my answer, you’ll find that their glb is $r$.Once you’ve done this a few times, you should be able to do it without actually turning the diagram upside-down: the glb of $x$ and $y$ is the highest element $u$ such that $u\le x$ and $u\le y$. That means that if $z$ is any lower bound of $x$ and $y$, then $z\le u$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott i have few more doubts shall we move this to discussion room..

Comment: @BrianM.Scott why glb of e and t is r? how e is connected to r?

Comment: I’m sorry: I hit the wrong letter by accident.. I meant $d$ and $t$.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11353/discussion-between-user200942-and-brian-m-scott ... will you help me clear more doubts here @BrianM.Scott

Comment: I don’t have a lot of time right now, but I can be there for a bit.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott okkk. will you tell me why glb of d and t is r but not g or o?

Comment: For the same reason that the lub of $n$ and $g$ is $r$ and not $s$ or $t$: $r,g$, and $o$ are all lower bounds of $d$ and $t$, but only $r$ is their **greatest** lower bound. The lower bounds $g$ and $o$ are all less than $r$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I’ll use the following Hasse diagram of a partial order (taken from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355393/topological-sorting-in-linear-order-for-hasse-diagram)) as an example. It isn’t the Hasse diagram of a lattice, but it’s fine for illustrating greatest lower bounds and least upper bounds.

[image]

If $x$ and $y$ are elements of a partial order, an upper bound for $x$ and $y$ is simply an element $u$ such that $x\le u$ and $y\le u$; $u$ is the **least** upper bound of $x$ and $y$ if $u$ is $\le$ all upper bounds of $x$ and $y$. Let’s look at a couple of examples.

Find the elements $n$ and $g$. What elements $x$ have the property that $n\le x$ **and** $g\le x$? Those are the upper bounds of $n$ and $g$. It’s not hard to see that $r$ is one of them: you can get from $n$ to $r$ by travelling upwards in the diagram, and you can also get from $g$ to $r$ by travelling upwards in the diagram. Similarly, $s,t$, and $u$ are upper bounds for $n$ and $g$. There are two more that are a little harder to spot: $d$ and $a$ are also upper bounds for $n$ and $g$, for the same reason: you can get to each of them from both $n$ and $g$ by travelling upwards in the diagram. On the other hand, $i$ is not an upper bound for $n$ and $g$: $n\le i$, but $g\not\le i$. Now look at the set of upper bounds for $n$ and $g$: it’s $\{r,s,t,u,d,a\}$. The lowest member of that set is $r$: $r\le r,r\le s,r\le t,r\le u,r\le d$, and $r\le a$. That makes $r$ the least upper bound of $n$ and $g$.

What about $j$ and $r$? The elements above $j$ are $b,c,e,m,l,a,k,d,i,t,u$, and the elements above $g$ are $r,d,a,u,s,t$; the elements that are above **both** $j$ and $g$ are therefore $a,d,u,t$, so these four elements are the upper bounds of $j$ and $g$. Here, howver, we do not have a **least** upper bound: $d\le d,d\le a$, and $d\le u$, but $d\not\le t$, and none of $a,u$, and $t$ is $\le d$.

Now look at $b$ and $s$: the elements above $b$ are $c$ and $e$, and the elements above $s$ are $t$ and $u$, so there is no element that is above both $b$ and $s$. This means that $b$ and $s$ have no upper bound in this partial order. (In a lattice that could not happen: by definition every pair of elements of a lattice has a least upper bound.)

Finally, look at $d$ and $i$: $a$ and $u$ are upper bounds for $d$ and $i$ (and the only ones), but $a\not\le u$ and $u\not\le a$, so neither of them is a **least** upper bound for $d$ and $i$. This shows that two elements of a partial order can have upper bounds without having a least upper bound. (Again, this cannot happen in a lattice.)

Comment: On the other hand, i is not an upper bound for n and g: n≤i, but g≰i i couldnt get why g</i

Comment: @user200942: There is no path upward from $g$ to $i$. If you start at $g$ and go up, the first step can only be to $r$. From $r$ you can go to $d$ or to $s$. From $d$ you can go to $a$ or to $u$, and from $s$ you can go only to $t$. Finally, from $t$ you can go only to $u$. Thus, there’s no way to reach $i$.

Comment: Now look at b and s: the elements above b are c and e, and the elements above s are t and u, so there is no element that is above both b and s... why @brian

Comment: is that like something we need a transitive relation to procced further..

Comment: @user200942: Isn’t it obvious that if the only elements above $b$ are $c$ and $e$, and the only elements above $s$ are $t$ and $u$, then there is nothing that is above **both** $b$ and $s$? The sets $\{c,e\}$ and $\{t,u\}$ have no members in common. // Yes, we’re dealing **only** with transitive relations. Specifically, we’re dealing only with partial orders.

Comment: thank you so much sir, but i need some more examples with the same justifications.. is it  pooosible?

Comment: @user200942: Random examples would serve little purpose at this point. It would be much better if you found an example of your own, tried to work out some least upper bounds in it, and posted a separate question about pairs of elements that caused you trouble.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11353/discussion-between-user200942-and-brian-m-scott)